Time series seasonality analysis - scoring method
I am working on the seasonal search in a time series and would like to automate the process with notations from the series, without having to manually inspect the curves. The three scores I propose to assess seasonality are:
Strength of seasonality: After using STL decomposition (LOESS) with python I recover three components: the trend, the seasonality and residue. I measure the proportion of variance explained by the seasonal component in relation to noise. I iterate using different value of the parameter 'period' of STL.
Seasonal similarity: With the seasonal component, I compare seasonal sub-periods to check consistency of patterns from one period to another.
Seasonal patterns: Analyses the repetition of patterns (ups/downs) between sub-periods of the seasonal component to assess stability of seasonality.
I apply these 3 scores with the decomposition STL (from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import STL) of python with the parameter "period" which allows to define the seasonality period and I retrieve the scores.
Do you think these notations are consistent with automating the search for seasonality? Do you know other effective methods for this? Perhaps classification methods? I would like to be able to know the strongest seasonal period for each breakdown from different data breakdowns (weekly, monthly, quarterly).
